# How to move Private-Public-logs from old SBS 2003 Exchange to new intall of SBS 2003

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003, disaster-recovery, windows-sbs-2003

This is what we have, a crashed SBS 2003 with Exchange 2003. The Exchange priv, pub and log files are located on another RAID array and the Exchange data is OK.

I want to install another SBS 2003/Exchange Server with the same configuration information as the crashed OS. How do I get the new Exchange to use the old priv, pub and log files? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you not have backups of the server and do you not have a way to get the server up and running again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the workings of SBS, but I imagine the steps you should take are similar to "normal" Windows Server.

What you'd ordinarily do is a system state recovery, to bring back Active Directory to a state before the crash. While your .edb files and transaction logs may be intact, Exchange stores an awful lot of configuration data in Active Directory, so by themselves the files you have aren't that helpful. It's quite possible the databases won't even mount without the correct configuration data in Active Directory.

If you don't have a recent backup, you could try starting from scratch and create a brand new empty Exchange database, dismount it, replace its .edb and transaction logs with yours and see if it mounts. If your users are all gone with the crashed server, you'll have to create new ones and reconnect the mailboxes to the appropriate users.

Comment: Ben, Thanks for your suggestion.  I have an image of the server but the image has an MFT error.  I will attempt to correct the error and see if I can bring the server up.  If that works great if not I will try your suggestion of starting from scratch.  I am out of state taking my daughter to FSU will give a short when I get back in state early next week.  Thanks and I appreciate your suggestions.